# fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms - Postfix + Dovecot

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I am trying to configure a simple email server that uses dovecot for the auth. I am inexperienced with the email procedures and I can't figure out what the problem is here:

`postfix/smtpd[26148]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms`

My postfix's config file:

```
tpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noplaintext,noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth-client
```

My dovecot config:

```
auth_mechanisms = plain cram-md5
auth_verbose = yes
base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.info
log_path = /var/log/dovecot
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/auth
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  chroot = login
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
  user = dovecot
}
service imap {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
}
service pop3-login {
  chroot = login
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
  user = dovecot
}
service pop3 {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
valid_chroot_dirs = /var/spool/vmail
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}
```

What is wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your socket private/auth-client exists. Try to replace with:
`smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth` in main.cf.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I had to generate a TLS certificate and make dovecot and postfix use it.
The private/auth file will be generated by dovecot automatically after that.

Comment: Can you explain the steps to do that?